# updated server, now need to show latest update in ListView

Tags: android, rest, listview

I have an app which shows a list of the funds from this api in a listView via asynctask. I want create a button in which they will be able to add a new fund by doing a POST command. How can I get this latest entry to show in the listView ?
Should I recall my asynctask? That seems redundant. Could there be a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either do that or once you make your first GET request and you get the List of whatever Object you use to populate your ListView, save it globally. After that make your POST request and if it succeeds just add your new entry to the List you saved and update your adapter. No need to make another GET request.